# What is this weird white border that's appearing around my HTML input submit button?

Tags: html, css, background, submit

Here's a screenshot.

[image]

And my CSS markup:

```
.submitbutton
{
    background: url("/Content/SiteImages/button.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 26px;
    width: 76px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-top: 12px;
}
```

Also, I'd like the background image to stretch to fit into the dimensions of the button. Currently it's displaying full size (I think). Any tips for this new HTML web developer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTML buttons always have a border, simply setting `border:0;` should fix this.

Comment: +1 Only thing I would add would be the width should be the width of the background image.

Comment: @PlagueEditor: Yes that's the missing piece. How would I set the image to stretch to fit the button? Currently it's size is huge, exceeding it's boundries.

Comment: You can either change the width of the .submitbox to fit the actual image width, or resize the image to fit the .submitbox width. There is no resizing of images in the background.

Comment: @Sergio I am not sure if a html button will allow you to do it JQuery you could do it like this:
`<a href="#" onclick="$('form').submit()"><img src="/path/to/image.png" /></a>`  Then you just adjust your image to fill the div or whatever in its wrapper.  But you will need to download JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try stating

```
background: 0; outline: 0;
```

on it.

***Note:*** This should only be used for testing purposes, disabling the outline makes people who navigate with their keyboards to not receive feedback when focusing on your button.

If it works, try using a more subtle outline.